# Problems with horizontal nav bar

Tags: html, css

I am working on a horizontal navigation bar with a dropdown menu. I'm quite new to making codes so this is maybe a stupid question. My navigation is sticking to the left of my website, but I need it to stay in line with the text and I can't get the navigation bar threw my whole webpage how do I fix this?

photo of my website with the 2 problems:

[image: Screenshot of website]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gdAZ.png)

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
}

.horizontal {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 40 auto;
  width: 640px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horizontal>li {
  float: left;
}

.horizontal li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.horizontal li:hover ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.horizontal li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 22px 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 1px solid #607987;
  background-color: #006600;
  letter-spacing: .08em;
  width: 70px;
}

.horizontal li a:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: #a2becf
}

.horizontal li:first-child a {
  border-left: 0;
}

.horizontal li:last-child a {
  border-right: 0;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mainnav">
  <ul class="horizontal">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="planning/planning.html" title="">Planning</a></li>
    <li><a href="takken/takken.html" title="">Takken</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="takken/kapoenen/kapoenen.html">Kapoenen</a></li>
        <li><a href="takken/kawellen/kawellen.html">Kawellen</a></li>
        <li><a href="takken/kajo's/kajo.html">Kajoo's</a></li>
        <li><a href="takken/jojoo's/jojoo.html">Jojoo's</a></li>
        <li><a href="takken/Givers/givers.html">Givers</a></li>
        <li><a href="takken/Jin/jin.html">Jin</a></li>
        <li><a href="takken/Akabe/akabe.html">Akabe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="kleding/kleding.html" title="">Kleding</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact/contact.html" title="">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="contact/leiding/leiding.html">Leiding</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact/verhuur/verhuur.html">Verhuur</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="inschrijven/inschrijven.html" title="">Inschrijven</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things in your css are giving you trouble.

`nav{ position: absolute; }` means this div will not fill the width.

`horizontal{ margin: 40 auto;}` 40 is not valid.
You MUST specify a measurement unit in CSS, so it should be 40px if I'm guessing your intention, but other units are available.

Here is amended css you can try.

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #006600;
}

.horizontal {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 640px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: That helped me a lot! thank you! but now if my dropdown menu pops up, the whole area turns green, I added a photo of my problem

Comment: give the `nav` element a height value of so many px, and also `overflow: visible;`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) **Add HTML:**

Example

```
<!-- The navigation menu -->
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Planning</a>
  <a href="#">Takken</a>
  <a href="#">Kleding</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">Inschrijven</a>
</div>
```

***And CSS:***

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow: auto;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 15%;; /* Four links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
}
```